# Vectorizing a nested for-loop in python for index-dependent function

Tags: python, c++, arrays, numpy

I'm currently porting a C++ program to Python using Numpy arrays.  I'm looking for a way to implement, if possible, the following loops in a more Pythonic way:

```
for (int j = start_y; j < end_y; j++)
    {
        for (int i = start_x; i < end_x; i++)
        {
            plasmaFreq[i][j] = plasmaFreq_0*(tanh((i - 50)/10) - tanh((i - (nx - 50))/10))/2.0;
        }
    }
```

Above, plasmaFreq_0 is a constant passed into the surrounding function, as is nx.  Obviously it's easy to vectorize the loop bounds to operate on a particular region of a numpy array, but this leaves me with the issue of how to map the above index-dependent function across the array.

Comment: Your calculation of `plasmaFreq[i][j]` currently has no reference to `j`; is that correct?

Comment: That's correct for this loop.  It's necessarily a two-dimensional array elsewhere in the program, but here, I am establishing a profile in the x-direction that is constant in the y-direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need an array `i`,

```
i = np.arange(start_x, end_x)
plasmaFreq[start_x:end_x, start_y: end_y] = plasmaFreq_0 *(np.tanh((i - 50)/10) - np.tanh((i - (nx - 50))/10))/2.0
```

I think that broadcasting should take it from there.

---

Note that your original code is quite inefficient<sup>1</sup>...  First, you're calculating the right hand side for each `j`, but it doesn't depend on `j`, so you only really need to calculate it once.  Second, your inner loop is over the slow index so you won't be effectively using your cache.  I would probably write it as:

```
for (int i = start_x; i < end_x; i++)
{
    rhs = plasmaFreq_0*(tanh((i - 50)/10) - tanh((i - (nx - 50))/10))/2.0;
    for (int j = start_y; j < end_y; j++)
    {
        plasmaFreq[i][j] = rhs;
    }
}
```

<sup><sup>1</sup>*How* inefficient depends on how well the compiler can do figuring out the loops.  Someday maybe some compilers could generate the same code from yours and mine</sup>

Comment: Is this more efficient than directly implementing the loops?

Comment: @Scott -- Usually, but when it comes to efficiency, usually it's best to forget what you think you know and just `timeit`.  Even the pros are frequently surprised by the results.